# Image not displayed perfectly on table cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitableview, uiimageview

I use auto layout and building app for iOS 7. I am using a custom `UITableViewCell`. I want to display an `UIImageView` inside it with some margin from `contentView`'s borders. So I have taken an `UIView` which has margin from `contentView`'s borders. `UIImageView` that I want to display is put into this `UIView` with all edges touching its superview.

Now, issue is the `UIImage` (green background) which is set to `UIImageView` is not displayed perfectly. By perfectly I mean that it is displayed but bottom 1px is not displayed. I have set image in storyboard and it looks perfect there as shown below.

[image]

But when I run the app then it looks as shown below. Concentrate on bottom black line which is clearly visible in storyboard but not when I run the app.

[image]

Please note that cell height in storyboard is 95pts. Image height is 77pts (non-retina). Also when I scroll cell up and down then I see that during scrolling this bottom line is visible, but that time top lines is not properly visible.

Comment: in simulator, test this in 100% scale size (_command+1 or simulator menu > window > scale > 100%_) or check if this issue occurs on the device as well. if it does then try a cell height of 96pts (_not sure, just checking_)

Comment: @staticVoidMan Yes, it was showing fine in device. You can post this as an answer.

Comment: ok, i have posted an answer... _glad it sorted your issue_

Comment: set border for cell content view, and add masksTobounds property for UIImageView.

Comment: @VineeshTP I don't set border. Its part of image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed such sub-pixelization issues when the simulator is in less than 100% scale size.
Especially on scrolling, when you notice it's sharpness fluctuates, it basically indicates that it's not being rendered properly.

So, test this scenario in the iOS simulator in 100% scale size

- `command+1`
  **or...**
- `simulator menu > window > scale > 100%`.

Alternatively, test this scenario on a device as well since it'll be more "*realistic*".

If the issue persists then give ***even*** numbers in the frame size and/or avoid float values <sup>*(*but don't quote me on this*)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with autolayout and CustomCell with a specific image.

What I did was ticking **clip subviews**, and the problem was gone. You can tick it in IB by checking `imageView` and go to **Attributes Inspector**:

[image: Clip Subviews]

Considering that your autolayout is correct, this question may help.

But anyways give it a try and give me feedback